# Using old java EE in Eclipse

Tags: java

I have a project that utilizes many different APIs and frameworks and I am struggling to get it running. The basic idea is to access informations from a database and provide different options for visualization of the data. I’m not familiar with many of the tools used in the project, such as Apache Tomcat, Hibernate and Spring frameworks.

Initially, I didn’t even have java EE installed (only had a JSE). So I installed it via the Eclipse (help -> install new software). I have also installed Spring IDE and STS, Apache Tomcat and XAMPP. The project still has many errors and doesn’t run. The student who passed me the project told me  that I must use java EE 5 library.

I don’t know how to do this once I have a newer version of java (1.8) and java EE. I tried to search some topics about this, but I don’t understand some dependencies and class path configurations. I am using Eclipse Luna in Mac Yosemite.

Comment: it's unclear what you're asking. are you asking for help configuring eclipse to use an older version of java EE rather than your system's default installation?

Comment: Yes, I thought this was the problem, but I fixed the compilation errors after downloading a java EE api jar file and adding that to my build path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you'll get answer on this question, it is very abstract. It's realy difficult to understand what problem whis project is. Try learn error's, find apropriate jar's at http://www.findjar.com and add to your project lib folder and add all jars as dependency to project. May be you should switch to older java version on your operating system, but I don't know exactly if MacOS Yosemit support java 6 or java 5. 
To use java for development, you must install JDK (java development kit), all additional libraries you should dowload or add as dependecy to pom.xml if you use apache maven.